# demonstrate the following segment relationship

Tags: geometry

It is a scalene triangle and its respective diagonals have been constructed, which do not keep any particular property, demostrate the following segment relationship
[image]

The demonstration is clear when $ P $ is a barycenter, any ideas to demonstrate the following?

Comment: Why do believe it is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an arbitrary triangle $XYZ$, let $[XYZ]$ denote its area.

If we scale triangle $ABC$ by any positive factor, the ratios remain the same, hence we can assume $[ABC]=1$.

Define $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$ by
\begin{align*}
&a_1=[PAM],&&\!\!\!\!\!\!a_2=[PAN]\\[4pt]
&b_1=[PBN],&&\!\!\!\!\!\!b_2=[PBL]\\[4pt]
&c_1=[PCL],&&\!\!\!\!\!\!c_2=[PCM]\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

[image]

Hence using area ratios, we get
\begin{align*}
&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\begin{cases}
{\Large{\frac{|PL|}{|AL|}}}={\Large{\frac{c_1}{c_1+c_2+a_1}}}\\[4pt]
{\Large{\frac{|PL|}{|AL|}}}={\Large{\frac{b_2}{b_2+b_1+a_2}}}\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\frac{|PL|}{|AL|}=\frac{c_1+b_2}{(c_1+c_2+a_1)+(b_2+b_1+a_2)}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\frac{|PL|}{|AL|}=c_1+b_2\\[4pt]
&\;\,\text{and by analogous reasoning, we get}\\[4pt]
&\frac{|PM|}{|BM|}=c_2+a_1\\[4pt]
&\frac{|PN|}{|CN|}=b_1+a_2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence
$$
\frac{|PL|}{|AL|}
+
\frac{|PM|}{|BM|}
+
\frac{|PN|}{|CN|}
=
(c_1+b_2)+(c_2+a_1)+(b_1+a_2)
=
1
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I had an idea similar to that you show me ... I didn't know that property

Excuse me, could you explain how to do this:


From an outer point to an equilateral triangle, they are drawn perpendicular to all three sides, the excess of the sum of two said perpendicular to the third is a fundamental line

Comment: In the edited version, there's no mention of an equilateral triangle. Perhaps ask that as a _new_ question.

Comment: It is another exercise, I have problems to prove it ... there was one similar that asked me to prove when the point is internal to the equilateral triangle ... but now, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I did it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320482/from-an-outer-point-to-an-equilateral-triangle

Comment: I'll look at it.