# From an outer point to an equilateral triangle,

Tags: geometry

From an outer point to an equilateral triangle, they are drawn perpendicular to all three sides, the excess of the sum of two said perpendicular to the third is a fundamental line

This exercise was complicated because the point was external, in another exercise the point was internal and it was easy to prove that the sum of these perpendicular ones gave a fundamental line. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What is a fundamental line?

Comment: Let me upload a graph, will it?

Comment: It appears that "fundamental line" is the [altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)) of the triangle.

Comment: After trying this in GeoGebra the assertion appears to be true if the outer point is placed within the area covered by one of the three angles of the triangle. But if the point is placed outside these areas, e.g above point $B$ on the line $LB$, the assertion doesn't hold. In that case, two of the distances must be subtracted from the third.

Comment: If I wrote the exercise at the beginning, I enclose the graph and just proved in geogebra that (for example) that thesis is fulfilled. Now what you mention is true, the exercise never mentions that perpendicular is restored I gave THAT example that was at least fulfilled. Could you help how to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an elegant proof:

With area matching, and help of $a$, the side length of the triangle,

$∆CAT + ∆CBT - ∆ABT = ∆ABC$

$\frac{1}{2}an + \frac{1}{2}am - \frac{1}{2}ac = \frac{1}{2}ah$

which yields

$n + m - c = h$

Comment: You're right! It did not occur to me, thank you very much!